# Capture groups bound by words AND containing certain words

Tags: regex, pcre, autoit, regex-lookarounds

I want to solve the following problem using regular expressions alone: a multi-line string in which information is separated by `Z!` on one end and `S0634` at the other, like :

```
Z! EXT .000 ...HOUSE... L24JN7   
PERSONAL COMPUTER\J\039060-L24JN7-000-*****-*****-
Payroll No.: 1
 -Name: 
 -Folios: 
 -Date: 6/24/2014
 -Subformat: S0634
Z! EXT .000 ...HOUSE... L24JN7   
PERSONAL COMPUTER\J\039060-L24JN7-000-*****-*****-
Payroll No.: 2
 -Name:  
 -Date: 6/24/2014
 -Subformat: S0634
Z! EXT .000 ...HOUSE... L24JN7   
PERSONAL COMPUTER\J\039060-L24JN7-000-*****-*****-
Payroll No.: 3
 -Name: 
 -Folios: 
 -Date: 6/24/2014
 -Subformat: S0634
desired content.</li>
```

I want to capture only groups bounded by mentioned two-character sequences AND contain the word `Folios` (one group in the middle does not have it, only 2 groups do).

I know how to split into groups and can also return the group that does *not* have it (e.g. `(Z!\s*EXT(?:(?!-Folios:).)*?S0634)`). However, how to capture groups that *do* have it eludes me. I am only interested in regular expression single line of code solutions (I know I could disassemble into groups to then check each group).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$regex = '~(?sm)Z!(?:(?!S0634).)*?Folios.*?S0634~';
preg_match_all($regex, $yourstring, $matches);
// See all matches
print_r($matches[0]);
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/20), you can see that the middle group is excluded.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Z! EXT .000 ...HOUSE... L24JN7   
PERSONAL COMPUTER\J9060-L24JN7-000-*****-*****-
Payroll No.: 1
 -Name: 
 -Folios: 
 -Date: 6/24/2014
 -Subformat: S0634  

    [1] => Z! EXT .000 ...HOUSE... L24JN7   
PERSONAL COMPUTER\J9060-L24JN7-000-*****-*****-
Payroll No.: 3
 -Name: 
 -Folios: 
 -Date: 6/24/2014
 -Subformat: S0634
)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?s)` activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- `Z!` matches the starting delimiter
- `(?:(?!S0634).)*?` lazily matches any chars that are not followed by `S0634`, up to...
- `Folios`
- `.*?S0634` lazily matches the rest of the string up to the closing delimiter

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
- [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)
- [Repetition with Star and Plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
Z!(?>(?!Z!).*\R)+?\s*-Folios:(?>(?!Z!).*\R)*?.* S0634
```

The `(?!Z!)` avoid to match next groups that have `Folios`. This ensures that `Folios` and `S0634` are in the same group.

Comment: +1 for alternative solution, you're always really good about using atomic groups! :)

Comment: @KEHT You could repeat Caz'z "line skipper" like this: `Z!(?>(?!Z!).*\R)+?\s*Payroll No.: 3(?>(?!Z!).*\R)+?\s*-Folios:(?>(?!Z!).*\R)*?.* S0634`—or using a subroutine.